# How to better understand IPv6 to block requests

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

With IPv4, whenever I realize any strange requests coming to my server I can easily block the IPv4 from further requests (I can block on my iptablets, or in my `.htaccess` file...). However with IPv6 it's not that easy because it's pretty simple to change the IP address, or even worse, it's pretty easy to rotate thousands of IPv6 addresses to make thousands of requests in a short time coming all from different IP addresses.

With IPv4 this was not such a big problem because it would be very expensive to own/rotate thousands of IPv4 addresses. Even companies like Linode or Digital Ocean make lots of questions to you if you start adding more than a few IP address on your account (even if you pay for those addresses, they will make you lots of questions like if you are using those addresses to send spam, to DDoS...).

So my question is this: in the IPv6 address, is there some "part" or "substring" (that is mostly fixed) that I can reliably blacklist since the other "part" (that changes) is probably from the same person or the same network? Take for example this address:

```
2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:1111:2222:3333
```

Can I tell, from the address above, that if I block all the IPs containing "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:1111" it will probably come from the same person/computer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never be 100% sure, because various ISPs and hosting providers do things differently (and sometimes very very wrongly). But as a rule a cloud provider will assign a /64 to a virtual network, and every VM in that virtual network will get IP addresses from within that /64 in various different ways. Providers leasing bare metal ("dedicated") servers typically assign a /64 to each physical machine.

It gets a bit more complicated for home connections, but as a rule, unless the subscriber has made configuration changes (few do, as for the most part it's IT pros who want more than a /64 at home) they also will have a /64 for their entire residence.

So, as the above suggests, blocking the /64 is likely to get rid of most malicious actors who know how to rotate their IPv6 address.

You may find [RFC 6177](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6177) interesting reading. Mainly as a baseline to see how various providers do it wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! Regarding blocking the /64 address space, means that I can "discard" the last 2 `:` from the address? In the example I provided on #1 means I can discard the `2222:3333` from the address since the user can freely change/assign new addresses to that part?

Comment: You are not familiar with subnetting? /64 is half of the 128-bit address, not one quarter.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with subnetting. I was just assigned this task to blacklist some ipv6. So it's 128 bits long, right? 64 is half, but is the first half or the second half? In the example I provided, I should block something like `2001:0db8:85a3:0000`?